# Set default image in FILES renderObj with FAL

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, fal

the following typoscript searches a random subpage and renders the first image which is referenced in the media field. It works. But i need a default image when the media field is empty.

```
page.10 = COA_INT
page.10 {
  10 = CONTENT
  10 {
    table = pages
    select {
      orderBy = rand()
      max = 1
      pidInList = 34
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {

      5 = FILES 
      5 {
        references {
          table = pages
          uid.data = current:uid
          fieldName = media
        }
        begin = 0
        maxItems = 1
        renderObj = IMAGE
        renderObj {
          file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with

```
file = fileadmin/....
file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
file.treatIdAsReference = 1
```

or

```
file.import.ifEmpty = fileadmin/....
```

or whith override but it seems that the whole FILES-Object is empty when there is no file in field media and so ifEmpty is not reached.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Edit: 
TYPO3 6.2

Comment: I would move the `override` one level up to the first `renderObj`.

Comment: This hint took me on the right path. I was able to solve my problem yet.

Comment: Just as a side-note:

`
        renderObj {
          file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
          file.treatIdAsReference = 1
        }
`

can be optimized like

`
        renderObj {
          file.import.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
        }
`

It is also possible to use the alt + title from the sys_file_reference

`
     titleText.data = file:current:title // file:current:alternative
     altText.data = file:current:alternative // file:current:title
`

Comment: Right - when using file:current:publicUrl then treatIdAsReference is not necessary - only when using file:current:uid (not: file:current:originalUid - thats wrong.) I corrected my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgampe gave me the right hint - override or `ifEmpty` have to start one level up:

```
5.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = IMAGE
5.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
      file = fileadmin/ .....
      file.height = 200c
      file.width  = 200c
}
```

Comment: You should accept this answer (even if this is your own).

Comment: I tried but got the answer that i can accept my answer in two days - curios.

Comment: Ah ok. Properly some kind of spam protection.